# Xcode how do I move a button's position through code?

Tags: uibutton, xcode5

Hello I am trying to move a button by using this code:

```
Next.center = CGPointMake(100,100);
```

It works for moving images but it obviously isn't working for buttons. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!!

Comment: where are you calling this method from?  Also, is "`CGPointMake(100),100);`" a typo with the extra paraneth?

Comment: It is called multiple times in my viewController depending on what the user does. One of them is the viewDidLoad.